# FileChannel.read() fail to throw ClosedByInterruptException

Tags: java, android, filechannel

There is a simple situation like:

**Thread A**: try to read from a `FileChannel` like

```
    length = tun.read(tunPacket.buffer);
```

This operation is block the this A thread.

**Thread B**: wait for a user input, (Stop button). When this event happens, calls A's `interrupt()` method. Despite the fact that `FileChannel` is implements `AbstractInterruptibleChannel`, this is not throw `ClosedByInterruptException`

I'm using Android 6.0, if matter, and there is [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer))

I'm trying to resolve this problem but looks impossible...

Comment: Hmmm, from the doc, using a common sens, I think that you should rather call `close` on `FileChannel`(in Thread B) not `interrupt()` the thread A ...

Comment: Interesting, I tried this, but there is no any `AsynchronousCloseException` or any exception.

Comment: yeah ... but what tun.read(..) returns then? isn't it -1? ... so you will know in the Thread A that something interrupt reading ... *but there is no any AsynchronousCloseException or any exception* from the doc it meant to be happend(no exception)

Comment: Sadly `length` never less than 0, I log it right after read. Looks like read() is not return anything after I close.

Comment: hmm it should throw: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/nio/FileChannelImpl.java#294 + https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java#109

Comment: Definitely seems like these ones must throw. Thank you for the help, I'm trying to figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
  length = tun.read(tunPacket.buffer);
```

> This operation is block the this A thread.

Clearly not. It wouldn't take long to execute, and your `interrupt()` could easily have missed it. You haven't presented any evidence that you were actually in that method at the moment `interrupt()` executed.